# 'SIGTERM' problem

Tags: opengl, sigterm

I have this problem that when there is an OpenGL application I am working on. When I try drawing this particular piece of code:

```
for (float i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex3f(cos(i), i, -10.0f);
}
glEnd();
```

I get this problem where the program crashes and returns:

> “SIGTERM”

Any suggestions to help me around this problem or any insight as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Although this is unrelated to your question, using floating-point numbers as loop variables is almost always a bad idea because of floating-point error accumulation. You should always keep the loop variable as an integer and convert to float internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBegin.xml), you need one `glBegin` per `glEnd` -- not the 10,000 or so you're doing!  So yank that `glBegin` to *before* the loop...

Comment: @thyrgle, you're welcome -- and, cheer up, oversights can and do happen to every single one of us!-)

Comment: That fixes the problem, but we got to wonder why it SIGTERMs... it should just trigger a GL error. (GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if glBegin is executed between a glBegin and the corresponding execution of glEnd.)